# Isolation, level shifter

Tags: isolation

I want to to shift  a signal which is varying from 1.2 to 3.3 volts ( a shifted square wave) to some other ground. I don't how to do this.
Frequency of this signal is 10 kHz with duty cycle around 10-60%.
And signals should be galvanic isolated.

Comment: We need more information.  Do you require galvanic isolation?  How far away (voltage) is the other ground reference?

Answer (score 2):

AC couple it and add a bias.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGGebb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage at the divider should be what you want the new average voltage to be.

Comment: I need isolation, I think it is not isolated signal.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjY734.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Use an optocoupler. On the second side, you'll need to provide your own secondary galvanicly isolated power at whatever voltage you want.